# How to add socket listener to HTML element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have a list of links. When each link loads I want to attach an socket listener to it. Currently I'm doing:

`$('a').click(function (event) { ... socket.on(...) })`

but I want something like

`$('a').onLoaded(function(event) ...)`

Thanks!

Comment: there is an attribute, onload="function()", try this

Comment: There's no such event for links. Even if there was, it probably wouldn't be a good idea to attach a new socket listener per link. It makes more sense to have one connection that delegates things out to specific links

Comment: I don't think anchor tags are supported with onload? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

Comment: What do you mean by "load", do you not redirect when you click an anchor, and if so what do you do? You can't attach sockets to anchors, but you can open new sockets? It's not really very clear at all what you're wanting to do here !

Comment: @ian hey you're right, I'll iterate through the links when the page is loaded and delegate events to a central socket listener. thanks.